# ¿La función Importxml (de Googlesheets) no funciona para el sitio web Skillshare?

Tags: html, google-hoja-de-cálculo, xpath, href

Hoy estoy aquí porque tengo un problema extraño al usar la función ImportXML en las Hojas de Google.

Estoy tratando de extraer los hrefs (facebook, twitter, youtube, etc.) de diferentes perfiles en 2 sitios web: udemy.com y skillhare.com.

Obtuve mi objetivo de los perfiles de Udemy, pero no obtuve suerte con Skillshare.

Después de intentar muchas veces (incluso con combinaciones extrañas de xpaths_query), creo que el problema podría ser por 2 causas: 1. El sitio web me está bloqueando (¿es esto posible?) 2. Mi xpath_query está mal... Sin embargo, todavía creo que la solución es fácil, pero no puedo verla.

Visita [mi hoja de Google con un par de muestras](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yr4ILEWULD5B7QsadUoPKHgPubSTOZlPCmFGmKWe6BM/edit?usp=sharing) para una mejor comprensión, puede encontrar más detalles en orden, allí ...

Mire ESTOS EJEMPLOS:
BUENOS RESULTADOS> Para Udemy, he usado la siguiente función de hoja de google

=IMPORTXML("https://www.udemy.com/user/saddam-kassim-2/"; "//div[@class='instructor-profile--social-links--3Kub5']/a/@href")

N/A RESULTADOS> Para Skillshare, he usado la siguiente función de hoja de google

=IMPORTXML("https://www.skillshare.com/user/sridhar"; "//div[@class='user-information-social-links']/a/@href")

Estas son las piezas de código html:
[UDEMY SAMPLE HTML](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yr4ILEWULD5B7QsadUoPKHgPubSTOZlPCmFGmKWe6BM/edit#gid=1295055932&range=B14)

[HTML DE MUESTRA COMPARTIDA](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yr4ILEWULD5B7QsadUoPKHgPubSTOZlPCmFGmKWe6BM/edit#gid=1295055932&range=C14)

Realmente aprecio tus pensamientos e ideas. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Qué puedo probar?
¡Gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 1):

`IMPORTXML` sólo puede extraer datos de código fuente del recurso referido por el URL, además,

- Sólo pueden obtener datos de nodos cuya ruta esté bien formada como `XHTML` (por ejemplo, el uso de etiquetas del tipo `<br />` puede evitar que `IMPORTXML` extraiga ciertos datos.
- No pueden obtener datos de páginas que han bloqueado el acceso a los robots de Google así como tampoco a si se han implementado medidas de bloqueo.